# Examples of liminf sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking to find an example of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ such that

liminf $a_n$ + liminf $b_n$ < liminf $(a_n+b_n)$

Ive found the proof for this thing but I am having the worse trouble coming up with an example for it. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: **HINT** Think about two alternate sequences whose sum is constant

Answer (score 2):

What about
$$a_n = (-1)^n \quad \text{and} \quad b_n = (-1)^{n+1} \quad ?$$